# Grunt watch failing to reload config file - errors on change

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

The environment is: Linux 2.6.32-573.12.1.el6.x86_64 x86_64, via SSH

I have a slightly non-standard setup for my grunt, as detailed below:

```
/home/scoots/public_html/
    grunt/
        package.json
        node_modules/
        project1/
            Gruntfile.js
        project2/
            Gruntfile.js
    project1/
    project2/
```

When I start grunt watch and make a change to my Gruntfile.js (Which is not a common occurance, but still something that might happen depending on the needs of the project), I get the following error:

```
$ cd ~/public_html/grunt/project1
$ grunt watch
Running "watch" task
Waiting...

Reloading watch config...
Fatal error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home'
```

It's simple enough to deal with (just cancel and restart grunt) - but that requires me to notice. I can sometimes try and carry on working, but grunt watch will now be locked-up.

Also, what's annoying is this code used to work when I had grunt installed on my local (Windows) machine and ran it from a Node.js command prompt.

For reference, here is an example Gruntfile.js that exhibits this problem:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);
    require('jit-grunt')(grunt);
    grunt.file.setBase('../');

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        site_dir: {
            site: '../tcl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child',
            jscache: 'wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/js/src',
            grunt: 'tcl'
        },
        watch: {
            css: {
                files: ['<%= site_dir.site %>/css/sass/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass', 'postcss'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
            scripts: {
                files: ['<%= site_dir.site %>/js/src/*.js'],
                tasks: ['include_file', 'uglify'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
            configFiles: {
                files: ['<%= site_dir.grunt %>/Gruntfile.js'],
                options: {
                    reload: true
                }
            }
        },
        sass: {
            options: {
                style: 'expanded', // compressed in postcss
                sourcemap: true,
                sourceMapEmbed: true,
                precision: 8,
                includePaths: ['node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets']
            },
            dist: {
                files: {
                    '<%= site_dir.grunt %>/css/layout.css': '<%= site_dir.site %>/css/sass/layout.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        postcss: {
            options: {
                map: {
                    inline: false,
                    annotation: '<%= site_dir.grunt %>/css/maps/'
                },
                processors: [
                    require('autoprefixer')({
                        browsers: [
                          "Android 2.3",
                          "Android >= 4",
                          "Chrome >= 20",
                          "Firefox >= 24",
                          "Explorer >= 8",
                          "iOS >= 6",
                          "Opera >= 12",
                          "Safari >= 6"
                        ]
                    }),
                    require('csswring')()
                ]
            },
            dist: {
                src: '<%= site_dir.grunt %>/css/layout.css',
                dest: '<%= site_dir.site %>/css/layout.min.css'
            }
        },
        include_file: {
            js: {
                cwd: '<%= site_dir.grunt %>/',
                src: [
                    '../<%= site_dir.site %>/js/src/common.js'
                ],
                dest: '<%= site_dir.grunt %>/js/'
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            options: {
                compress: {
                    warnings: true
                },
                mangle: true,
                preserveComments: /(?:^!|@(?:license|preserve|cc_on))/
            },
            build: {
                src: [
                    '<%= site_dir.grunt %>/<%= site_dir.jscache %>/common.js'
                ],
                dest: '<%= site_dir.site %>/js/common.min.js'
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass', 'postcss', 'include_file', 'uglify']);
};
```

And package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "3.3.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.4.1",
    "csswring": "^5.1.0",
    "grunt": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-include-file": "^0.1.3",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-sass": "^2.0.0",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.10.0",
    "time-grunt": "^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

EDIT: Verbose / debug enabled:

```
$ grunt -v -d watch
Initializing
Command-line options: --verbose, --debug=1

Reading "Gruntfile.js" Gruntfile...OK

Registering Gruntfile tasks.
Reading package.json...OK
Parsing package.json...OK
Initializing config...OK
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...OK
+ default

Running tasks: watch

Loading "grunt-contrib-watch" plugin

Registering "/home/scoots/public_html/grunt/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/tasks" tasks.
Loading "watch.js" tasks...OK
+ watch

Running "watch" task
[D] Task source: /home/scoots/public_html/grunt/node_modules/grunt-contrib-watch/tasks/watch.js
Waiting...
Verifying property watch exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.css.files exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.scripts.files exists in config...OK
Verifying property watch.config.files exists in config...OK
Watching ../tcl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/css/sass/__bookings.scss for changes.
Watching ../tcl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/css/sass/__variables.scss for changes.
Watching ../tcl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/css/sass/_bootstrap-custom.scss for changes.
Watching ../tcl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/css/sass/_contactform7.scss for changes.
Watching ../tcl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/css/sass/_lightslider.scss for changes.
Watching ../tcl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/css/sass/_lity.scss for changes.
Watching ../tcl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/css/sass/_zoom.scss for changes.
Watching ../tcl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/css/sass/layout.scss for changes.
Watching ../tcl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/js/src/bootstrap.js for changes.
Watching ../tcl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/js/src/common.js for changes.
Watching ../tcl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/js/src/instafeed.js for changes.
Watching ../tcl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/js/src/lightslider.js for changes.
Watching ../tcl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/js/src/lity.js for changes.
Watching ../tcl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/js/src/scrollreveal.min.js for changes.
Watching ../tcl/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen-child/js/src/zoom.js for changes.
Watching tcl/Gruntfile.js for changes.
Watching tcl/css for changes.
Watching tcl/js for changes.
Watching tcl/wp-content for changes.
Clearing require cache for "tcl/Gruntfile.js" file...OK

[[[[I edit the Gruntfile here]]]]

Reloading watch config...
Fatal error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home'
```

Comment: could you please run your grunt watcher with verbose and debug enabled? What is the output when running into the error?
`grunt -v -d`

Comment: I guess this part could be the one that makes grunt go crazy: `src: [
                    '../<%= site_dir.site %>/js/src/common.js'
                ],`
It seems like grunt gets confused and walks up some folders ../../ and tries to watch stuff directly from /home.

Comment: @DerAlex I've edited in the verbose/debug output into my post

Answer (score 0):

A leading slash in a files glob sometimes cause this error but grunt will not throw any errors. Just a silent fail with this warning.

make sure that your "files" config does not lead to this , and this <%= site_dir.site %> template does not lead to null or empty.

```
watch: {
            css: {
                files: ['<%= site_dir.site %>/css/sass/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['sass', 'postcss'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
            scripts: {
                files: ['<%= site_dir.site %>/js/src/*.js'],
                tasks: ['include_file', 'uglify'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
            configFiles: {
                files: ['<%= site_dir.grunt %>/Gruntfile.js'],
                options: {
                    reload: true
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey, the css/scripts watchers are working absolutely fine, so `<%= site_dir.site %>` can safely be ignored for this question.